# Repeating the same processes for different variables

Tags: python, validation, python-2.7, input

I'm writing code where I have to input a fighter and enemy strength and skill. Is there any efficient way of writing the program where it has to work in the same way e.g. checking each input is not `.isdigit` or more than 1,000,000, when it will ask for input again.

```
import random
import math

enemy_name="fierce dragon"
global enemy_name
fighter_name="undefeatable worrior"


def again_fighter_strength():
    global fighter_strength
    fighter_strength=raw_input("Please enter the strength of "+fighter_name+"(must 1M or below):")
    if fighter_strength.isdigit():
        fighter_strength=int(fighter_strength)
        if fighter_strength < 1000001:
            again_fighter_skill()
        else:
            print "Fighter strength must 1M or below"
            again_fighter_strength()
    else:
        print "Fighter strength must be a whole number."
        again_fighter_strength()


def again_fighter_skill():
    global fighter_skill
    fighter_skill=raw_input("Please enter the skill of your character(must 1M or below):")
    if fighter_skill.isdigit():
        fighter_skill=int(fighter_skill)
        if fighter_skill < 1000001:
            print""
            again_enemy_strength()
        else:
            print "Fighter Skill must 1M or below."
            again_fighter_skill()
    else:
        print "Fighter skill must be a whole number"
        again_fighter_skill()


def again_enemy_strength():
    global enemy_strength
    enemy_strength=raw_input("Please enter the strength of the "+enemy_name+"(must 1M or below):")
    if enemy_strength.isdigit():
        enemy_strength=int(enemy_strength)
        if enemy_strength < 1000001:
            again_enemy_skill()
        else:
            print enemy_name,"Enemy strength must 1M or below."
            again_enemy_strength()
    else:
        print "Enemy strength must be a whole number"
        again_enemy_strength()


def again_enemy_skill():
    global enemy_skill
    enemy_skill=raw_input("Please enter the skill of the "+enemy_name+"(must 1M or below):")
    if enemy_skill.isdigit():
        enemy_skill=int(enemy_skill)
        if enemy_skill < 1000001:
            print "your good to go"
        else:
            print enemy_name,"Fighter skill must be a whole number"
            again_enemy_skill()
    else:
        print "Fighter Skill must 1M or below"
        again_enemy_skill()

again_fighter_strength()
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You would do it in a function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write a function for python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939922/write-a-function-for-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the user input into a standalone function:

```
def get_int(prompt, min_=None, max_=1000000):
    """Gets a user input integer value between min_ and max_ (inclusive)."""
    while True:
        try:
            ui = int(raw_input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("Input must be an integer.")
        else:
            if max_ is not None and ui > max_:
                print("Input must be {0:,} or less.".format(max_))
            elif min_ is not None and ui < min_:
                print("Input must be {0:,} or more.".format(min_))
            else:
                return ui
```

This will loop indefinitely until the user enters acceptable input. You can call it, e.g.

```
fighter_strength = get_int("Please enter the strength of {0}.".format(fighter_name))
```

Comment: I got python 2.7.5 and it does seem to work it just prints out nothing with no error at all.Can you please type it for fighter_strength,fighter_skill and enemy_strength and enemy_skill Please reply ASAP I need this for GCSE.

Comment: Apologies, there was a logic error which I have now corrected (checking for `min_` and `max_` values). However, it certainly gave an error when I ran it.

Comment: I got a problem in the other code when I input a negative value it rejects it but this one somehow apcept it

Comment: Chears I got it change min value to ZERO

Comment: That's because `str.isdigit()` will only `return True` if *all* characters in the string are digits, rejecting e.g. `"-1"`; `int()`, however, will interpret the number, including the punctuation, without raising `ValueError`.

Comment: OK I another question similarly,I am probalybeingrediculus but is there a efficient way of writting this?

Comment: i can't postit have to make a new 1

Comment: Your comments make no sense. Efficient way of writing... what? Can't post/need to make new... what?

Comment: I did it in another quiestion please feel free to have a look